# Do classes not inherit static variables from the classes they extend?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I have a static variable named `debug` that I'm trying to access in my class that is generating an error.

> Access of possibly undefined property debug

The property is defined on the base class.

```
public class Animal {
    public static var debug:Boolean;
}

public class Meerkat extends Animal {

    public function Meerkat() {
        trace("debug:" + debug); // error here
    }
}
```

Can a class not access a static variable on it's super class?

*Update. This is odd. It seems the error went away but there is now a warning there with the same message as the error.*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's correct. Static variables are not inherited by subclasses. This is documented [here](https://help.adobe.com/en_US/ActionScript/3.0_ProgrammingAS3/WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118a9b90204-7fcd.html#WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118a9b90204-7f45), which also suggests working around it by declaring an instance variable with the same name. Not sure how useful of a workaround that is, since you might as well *change* the static variable to an instance one instead of having both (unless you really need to call `Animal.debug` elsewhere), but it's AS3, it's there.

Comment: I attempted a workaround to declare debug on my sub class as a static variable (not instance), same signature, and the error went away and a warning appeared. When I was stepping through the code later the debug variable was set to true in the IDE but it was skipped in the function code `if (debug)` as if it was false. Meaning the static var of the base class was true but the value of the subclass was being checked, which was false. Or so it seemed in my brief tests. Might or might not be the case but I'm going to remove the declaration from the base class and declare it on my subclasses.

Comment: @1.21 gigawatts: Judging by the name of the variable perhaps it would be better off as a const, or perhaps even a [conditional compilation flag](http://www.flashdevelop.org/wikidocs/index.php?title=AS3_Conditional_Compilation) (links to FlashDevelop docs but you can set them in the Flash IDE in your project's AS3 settings). If you need to be able to toggle debug mode on or off within your application, it should be in a separate class, not a property of each of your subclasses.

Comment: In some projects I've used conditional compilation but for this one I need to debug it at runtime so I can't use conditional compilation for that. The reason the property is on the class is because the class it extends has methods for logging on it. I could use a separate class but since each class has it's own responsibility and there are many I want to enable or disable for each specific class not globally if that makes sense.